# Assignment operator for functions

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what the assignment operator is used for when dealing with methods, functions, etc. Here is the example in w3 school for defining an object

```
function person(firstname,lastname,age,eyecolor){
this.firstname=firstname;
this.eyecolor=eyecolor;

this.newlastname=newlastname;
}
```

and this is the actual function (place somewhere else)

```
function newlastname(new_lastname){
this.lastname=new_lastname;
}
```

It's just very weird to me throughout javascript, you say

```
object.methodname = somefunctionname
```

Any ideas to help me conceptualize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question is effectively the same as this:

```
function person(firstname, lastname, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.eyecolor = eyecolor;

    //anonymous function assigned to newlastname property
    this.newlastname = function(new_lastname) {
        this.lastname = new_lastname;
    };
}
```

`person` is a constructor function (you would call it with the `new` operator to create a new instance). Every instance of `person` has three properties, `firstname`, `eyecolor` and `newlastname`.

The `newlastname` property is a *method* since it's value is a function. When you call that method, the instance of `person` on which it is called will get a `lastname` property.

For example:

```
var me = new person("James", "Allardice", 22, "Brown");
me.lastname; //undefined
me.newlastname("Something");
me.lastname; //Something
```

This is possible because in JavaScript, functions are objects.

Comment: properties are methods...? I'm so mind blown right now. Properties can have functions as values...what is this madness!!! (coming from c++/c#/objective-c)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a common reaction from developers more used to C/C++! The article lanzz linked to should help explain the general concept in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

This language feature is called [First-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function). The Wikipedia article is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

This is the cool thing about javascript. Functions are first-class objects, this means unlike other non-functional programming languages, you can hand them as parameters to other functions, return them from function and (like in your example) attach them to objects like a normal property.

This enables programming paradigmas like the (for the web) so important asynchronous function calls (callbacks).